# running eclipse from usb key: java enviroment error

Tags: java

I am trying to install Eclipse IDE in portable USB key.
Java is placed in
`f:\commonfiles\java64`. the sub folder `\bin` is in here
I set the environment path by running in `f:` drive the command '`Set Path=CommonFiles\Java64\bin;%Path%'`
although when I run eclipse it returns this error log:

https://ibb.co/7CWm3mw

I have set environment path by running: `Set Path=CommonFiles\Java64\bin;%Path%`
if i run `f:> where java` in returns same path

also , if i run `java -version` from above path `CommonFiles\Java64\bin` it gives:

```
java version "1.8.0_231
java (TM) SE Run time environment <build.......>
java Hotspot(TM) 64-bit server vm <.......>
```

I think i have to change some path in eclipse.ini but i dont know how.

Comment: Instead of putting a link to a random location you should copy the relevant content into the question.

Comment: sorry for mistake. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please define JAVA_HOME environment variable. It should point to your installed JDK version. I assume it is JDK since you are interested to run Eclipse. Usually it looks like the following:

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121
```